# SQLite statement for the update of a database in Android not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to Android and working on a simple To do list app in Android. 
Currently, I am running into a problem when trying to update the database with the value of a text field. The function is executed when the user clicks on a button. The value from the text field is fetched, that works fine. The problem is in the SQlite statement, but I couldn´t figure it out until now:

```
public void saveEntryClickFunction(View view) {

    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.task_description);
    String task = textViewToChange.getText().toString();
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(TaskActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = String.format("UPDATE %s SET '%s'",
            TaskContract.TABLE,
            TaskContract.Columns.TASK_DESCRIPTION,
           task_description);
    sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
    updateUI();
}
```

Any help on this issue would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually set your column equal to something. You're missing that in your update statement.

```
String sql = String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s = '%s'",
            TaskContract.TABLE,
            TaskContract.Columns.TASK_DESCRIPTION,
            task_description);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful